# Is it possible to see the individual data points in a Simulink scope?

Tags: matlab, plot, scope, simulink

A Simulink simulation generates a lot of data points, at fixed or variable time steps. After exporting the data, it is possible to plot it as a signal in Matlab, for instance using

> `plot(...,'--')` for a line plot or
>
> `plot(...,'.')` for a point plot.

In contrast, in a Simulink scope, it seems that you can only make a line plot.

Hence my question: is there a possibility to have a point plot in a Simulink scope? (I would like to see a point plot in a Simulink scope to see the behaviour of the step size of a variable step solver.)

Comment: From the [documentation](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/scope.html): Check out "Style Properties".

Answer (score 1):

As [`Stewie Griffin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2338750/stewie-griffin) pointed out, markers can be added under `view`-`style`:
[image]